# C# get all string combinations between 2 arrays

Tags: c#, loops, reflection, .net-assembly

I have 2 string arrays:

`string[] baseAssemblyNames`

For instance `['Core', 'Web', 'Data']`

`string[] projectAssemblyNames`

For instance `['Project1', 'Project2']`

Result:

`['Project1.Core', 'Project1.Web', 'Project1.Data', 'Project2.Core', 'Project2.Web', 'Project2.Data']`

I want all combinations between these 2, now I am using 2 foreach to iterate and combine them.

```
foreach(var projectAsm in projectAssemblyNames)
{
    foreach(var baseAsm in baseAssemblyNames)
    {
        try
        {
            var asm = Assembly.Load($"{projectAsm}.{baseAsm}");
            asmList.Add(asm);
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

Is there a better solution for this in terms of performance when we have a lot of projects where we want to load the assembly for scanning?

Comment: Please define "better". Better in terms of what? It *can* be done with LINQ and maybe that's easier to understand, but there's nothing inherently bad about these loops. What exactly are you looking to improve? If it's working as-is, it probably should be on [codereview.se].

Comment: Are you looking for a Linq solution that would be fewer lines of code?  Otherwise there's not much point in trying to improve performance.

Comment: Yeah we have a lot of projects where we use reflection to scan for classes, etc. I am looking to make this better instead of using multiple foreach loops.

Comment: This is more of an architectural/engineering question and should go on [Software Engineering](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com). Much more than just this little section of code would have to change to have an effect on performance.

Comment: The empty catch block will preclude you from using a _clean_ alternate in Linq.  Any performance problems you have is _not_ because of the nested loops.

Comment: *Is there a better solution for this in terms of performance* The answer is no. Whatever CPUs cycles you could possibly squeeze out of the language, it would be dwarfed by the time to load the assemblies, which is unavoidable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clean approach with LINQ ;)

```
var assemblies = projectAssemblyNames
    .Join(baseAssemblyNames, p => 1, b => 1, (p, b) => $"{p}.{b}")
    .Select(Load)
    .Where(assembly => assembly != null)
    .ToList();

Assembly Load(string assembly) 
{
    try
    {
        return Assembly.Load(assembly);
    }
    catch 
    { 
        return null; // Not found
    }
}
```

Comment: I usually fine query syntax to be nicer for cross joins.

Comment: Added some modifications but nice alternative solution using LINQ!